# Add dropdownlistbox PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

In my DataWindow, I am having a column object with style='EDIT'

When Add button is clicked , upon certain conditions I have to convert that EDIT style to Dropdownlistbox style with some data value and display value. Help me to do this.

Comment: Did you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should do this. If you change what an input does you may confuse your users. Write some use cases for the tasks the user needs to do. The use cases should not say what the screen looks like. Then you can design the screens to support the tasks. For tasks like adding a new item, a wizard is often a good choice. It's good for the user because the user always knows what the next thing to do is. It's good for you because you can control the order the user enters the data.